# Does load index affect towing performance?

Tags: tires, towing

Background: I tow a 4000lb camper and my current tires are 111 rated. Many of the replacement tires I'm looking at (buying 4) are rated at 107 (same speed index) and within the manufacturer's specs (2012 Dodge Durango).

Will I feel a difference in towing between the 111 and 107 load index?

Comment: You may feel a difference, but I doubt it would be from a load index. If there was a HUGE difference, then maybe. If the tires are from different manufacturers and/or constructed differently (say passenger vs light truck tires) then you may feel a difference. If the old tires are *really old* and/or completely worn out, you'd feel a difference. If the tread pattern is vastly different, then you'd feel a difference.

Comment: whats your tongue weight, and do you carry much load in the truck as well when hauling the trailer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tyre load index - see chart [here](http://www.tiresplus.com/tires/tire-buying-guide/tire-load-index-chart/) gives the load for that tyre, so the higher the rating the higher the load the tyre can carry. It does not reflect the tyre's towing performance.

The image shows the top section : 
[image: tyre load chart as sourced]